# How to find duplicates value in field from two tables and also in itself?

Tags: php, sql

I have read a post with almost the same title, but it didn't answer my question.
I have 2 table, table1 and table2. Both have col1 field

```
 SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table1
    GROUP BY
        col1
    HAVING 
        COUNT(col1) > 1
```

this code will give us data where col1 value is duplicated in table1, but I need to get value in col1 where the value is duplicated either in table1 OR table2, so there is 2 data having the same col1 value in table1, or same col1 value in table2
OR duplicated from 2 tables, so there is data in table1 where col1 = A, and there is data in table2 where col1 = A too.

Comment: Join the relevant fields from the two tables into a temp table first, then run the same query against that temp table.

Comment: i'm using phpmyadmin, how can i make temp table for that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the union of values from `table1` and `table2`, and then group and filter that result. Use `UNION ALL` so that you do not lose duplicates when the union is performed.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT col1 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1 from table2    -- you can change the column name as required
) AS blah
GROUP BY 1 HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Note the reference to the column by field number in the `GROUP BY`. This allows you to use different column names in the different tables without having to use `AS` to alias the column name.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you want group 2 table data? for example if there is a col1='a' in table 1 and col1='a' in table 2 you want show that data?
if yes , try this

```
select sel.col1 from (SELECT
        col1
    FROM
        table1
    GROUP BY
        col1
    union all
    SELECT
        col1
    FROM
        table2) sel
    GROUP BY
        sel.col1
    HAVING 
        COUNT(sel.col1) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use below:

1. UNION ALL - if they have the same information schema
2. Join the tables then used HAVING clause

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't care whether you find a value twice in table1 or twice in table2 or just once in table1 and once in table2; you consider all of these duplicates. So you want to look at the whole set built of all table1 records plus all table2 records. You get these with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT col1
FROM (SELECT col1 FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT col1 FROM table2) t
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```